# Symmetry with respect to the first bisector

Tags: coordinate-systems, symmetry

> Knowing the points $(3m+n,2)$ and $(2m+n,-1)$ are symmetric with respect to the first bisector, is it correct to say
>
> - $m-n=1$
> - $m-n=-5$
> - $m-n=-11$
> - $m-n=-13$
> - $m-n=15$

I think by first bisector, they mean the perpendicular bisector. So, the mid point is $\left(\dfrac{5m+2n}2,\dfrac12\right)$.

Not able to establish symmetry from here on.

Comment: first bissector = line with equation $y=x$.

Comment: @JeanMarie Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Jean Marie gave the hint that the first bisector meant the line $y=x$.

So, $$3m+n=-1\\2m+n=2\\\implies m=-3, n=8$$

So, the answer is $m-n=-11$